# google script copy document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to locate in the documentation but don't seem to find how to copy/move a newly created spreadsheet in Google Script, into a folder.
I can see how to do this with files, but apparently Documents/Spreadsheets are not regular files for Google script.

This code does not work:

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Reports');
newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(clientNames[0][0]);
nsc = newSheet.copy('new1');
folder.addFile(nsc);
```

error: **Cannot find method addFile(Spreadsheet)**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

I was trying to locate in the docs in Spreadsheets, Drive, Folder but still no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the ID of the copied spreadsheet. Then use the ID to get a reference to the copied spreadsheet with `DriveApp`. The reference is the file type. Then use the DriveApp file type in the `.addFile()` method:

```
function copySheet(date) {
  var folder, newSheet, nsc, nscID, theFileReference;

  folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Reports ' + date);
  newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("clientNamesABC" + date);
  
  nsc = newSheet.copy('new1');
  nscID = nsc.getId();//Get ID of copied Sheet
  
  theFileReference = DriveApp.getFileById(nscID);
  folder.addFile(theFileReference);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFilie(theFileReference);//Remove file from the root Drive
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you've been helpful

Comment: You may also want to add as a last line -  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFilie(theFileReferenced), as the file will still be in the root of My Drive, as is the process of SpreadsheetApp.create...